# Degree of freedom and Grubler formula

Tags: movement, mechanical-engineering

I am attempting to apply the Grubler formula (which can be found here: https://learnmech.com/how-to-calculate-degree-of-freedom-of/), but it does not seem to yield the expected result for the following problem:

Consider a planar mechanism with revolute joints (represented by small gray discs). The joints A and B are fixed to the frame (depicted by the dotted lines).

[image]

I get $$DOF = 3*(11 - 1) - 2*(2+2+3+1+2+2+3) = 0$$

However, the correct answer that was given to us in class is 1, not 0. Therefore, my questions are:

1. Am I applying the formula incorrectly?
2. If not, are there some cases where the Grubler formula should be avoided? If yes, how can I recognize these cases and what method could I use instead?